# What's diff between management console and admin console

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I get [1],[2],[3],[4] after running command with api-manager.bat,

- [1] https://localhost:9443/publisher
- [2] https://localhost:9443/devportal
- [3] https://localhost:9443/carbon
- [4] https://localhost:9443/admin

What's diff between [3] and [4]? Why we have two management console?

Answer (score 1):

[1] https://localhost:9443/publisher

You can access the Publisher portal from here. This is where developers develop their APIs. After creating the APIs, they can deploy and publish the API.

[2] https://localhost:9443/devportal

When you publish the API from the Publisher portal, those APIs are available in the Dev portal. The Dev Portal is where application developers discover APIs. It is a marketplace for APIs. They can select the APIs and subscribe to those APIs for using the APIs in their applications.

[3] https://localhost:9443/carbon

This is the carbon management console. This console is used by admins for creating and managing users, roles, registry,etc.

[4] https://localhost:9443/admin

This is the Admin portal which is also used by admins to create rate-limiting policies related to APIs, to create key managers, etc. This admin portal holds the admin tasks related to the API Management.